# Does anybody know what this is? bag 3, black, light grey, red Technic bricks, large gold wheels

Tags: set-identification

All I know is that it’s from 2011 bag 3 and I found number 135149 on it..

[image: bag 3, black, light grey, red Technic bricks, large gold wheels]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[76012-1 Batman: The Riddler Chase](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=76012-1)

Based on Red Technic, Brick 1 x 2 with Holes with Light Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Pin on Bottom - only 5 sets. And one of them looked *just* right, so I grabbed the color and wheel code from that one. And it fit!

[image: 76012-1 Batman: The Riddler Chase]

Comment: Dang, I was going the other way and looking for the unique-ish wheels (which ended up being hard to find) so I was too slow. [Found them](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=56145) but your answer popped up while I was still composing. Good work :)

Comment: So many wheels look pretty much the same to me. I find it frustrating to be half-done an answer and find someone else has already posted it, so I usually just post the answer as soon as I have it, and then go back and edit it with pictures and links and justification, so that it doesn't waste anyone else's time. I didn't here. Sorry. I would prefer there to be a way to lock an answer for a few minutes to avoid this, but that's not the Stack Exchange way.